# Hatching frequency on plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Suppose I have the following script that produces a plot (as shown below) where some datapoints have hatching. At DPI = 200, the hatching frequency (space between dots) is good, but if I want to increase the resolution of the plot (DPI = 600 for example), the dots become very fine. Is there a way to set the gap between dots? Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


Sig = np.random.rand(50,50)
Sig = np.ma.masked_greater(Sig, 0.25)

f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax1.pcolor(np.linspace(0,90,50),np.linspace(0,50,50),Sig, hatch=".",alpha=0)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 8)
fig.savefig('Trial.png',bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to accurately control the spacing between hatch patterns. You do have the option to *increase*  the hatch density though. Instead of `hatch = "."` you can add the symbol more often, `hatch="..."`; this will produce a denser pattern.

[image]

The above figure has been produced with standard dpi of 100.
Changing the dpi to 300 gives the following image:

[image]

As can be seen the issue of a changed hatch density for different dpi is not there anymore; it has been brought up in [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4108/) and afterwards been fixed. The solution is thus to update to the newest matplotlib version.

Comment: Ah. that makes sense given its not an issue for my personal laptop but the Anaconda dist. at work has this issue.